# jQuery widget $.ajax() .abort() "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined"

Tags: ajax, jquery, jquery-1.9, jquery-1.8

I have a widget that I created that uses an $.ajax() call to get data from the server. I allow the users to refresh the data from the server when they want, so I need to be able to cancel the existing request so that there is not a collision with multiple datasets returning from the server. Only a single request should be executed at a time.

---

```
Widget Code
(function ($) {
    $.widget("w.widgetName", {

        options: { { /*set the widget options here*/ }},

        _create: function () { /*do the create stuff here */ },

        _cancelAjaxRequest: function(){//private method to cancel the current ajax request
            var xhr = this.ajaxGetCall;
            if (xhr && xhr.readyState != 4){
                xhr.abort();//line that throws the error, but in the jQuery code
            }
        },

        refresh: function () {
            var self = this;

            self._cancelAjaxRequest();

            self.ajaxGetCall = $.ajax({//I assign the $.ajax() xhr object here
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "Application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                url: "url/goes/here",
                data: dataGoesHere,
                success: function (data) { /*Do stuff here*/},
                error: function (xhr, status, error) { /*Do stuff here*/},
                complete: function (r, s) { /*Do stuff here*/}
            });

        },

        destroy: function () {
            var self = this;
            self._cancelAjaxRequest();
            //do other stuff to destroy the object
        }
    });
} (jQuery));
```

---

Using both jQuery 1.8.2 and 1.9.1, I get the following error when executing `xhr.abort();`.

```
 TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
```

I put the full version of jQuery 1.8.2 and 1.9.1 and they both point to line 622.

```
each: function( obj, callback, args ) {
        var value,
            i = 0,
            length = obj.length,
            //remaining code removed for brevity
            }
```

---

I any help or insight to this problem that I am having is much appreciated!

---

Update: I have been doing a `console.log(xhr)` just to double check and make sure that I am getting an `xhr` object back. Here is a copy and paste from the Chrome console.

```
Object {readyState: 1, getResponseHeader: function, getAllResponseHeaders: function, setRequestHeader: function, overrideMimeType: function…}
abort: function ( statusText ) {
always: function () {
complete: function () {
done: function () {
error: function () {
fail: function () {
getAllResponseHeaders: function () {
getResponseHeader: function ( key ) {
overrideMimeType: function ( type ) {
pipe: function ( /* fnDone, fnFail, fnProgress */ ) {
progress: function () {
promise: function ( obj ) {
readyState: 0
setRequestHeader: function ( name, value ) {
state: function () {
status: 0
statusCode: function ( map ) {
statusText: "abort"
success: function () {
then: function ( /* fnDone, fnFail, fnProgress */ ) {
__proto__: Object
```

Comment: xhr is not what you think it is, now to figure out why

Comment: @Pinch, can you elaborate?

Comment: have you tested out your ajax freestanding, maybe it is not working and returning a bad xhr

Comment: @JoeFletch as far as i can tell the abort method doesn't call .each. Therefore, you must be calling .abort on something that isn't a jqxhr, though that then makes the error seem odd because how many other jquery objects have an abort method.

Comment: Click the down arrow on the error to get a stack trace. Follow that all the way up to where you used .abort, maybe that'l give you some insight as to what's going on.

Comment: @KevinB, I just updated my answer with details from the `console` about the object. I believe that I am getting an xhr object back.

Comment: Can you still navigate through the stack-trace to figure out where within the jquery core it's going to .each?

Comment: @KevinB, I never really used the stack trace before. I guess I never understood it! Either way I was able to track down the error which was in another bit of the code. Please post an answer and I will mark it as correct! Thanks for your help with this!

Comment: It would probably be more helpful to future users if you instead posted an answer showing what actually caused the problem and how you fixed it (and i'm curious)

Comment: Its hard to avoid a +1 comment for Kevin B

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [Kevin B](https://stackoverflow.com/users/400654/kevin-b)'s comments to my question, I used the stack trace in Chrome to get to the problem line of code.

Fortunately it has nothing to do with the code that I posted in my question. It is related to a function that I have written to handle errors from the server. Calling `xhr.abort()` forces the `error` method of `$.ajax()` to be called. I have a function assigned to the `error` method that was looking at the `xhr.responseText` and I failed to check to see if `xhr.responseText` was not `null` and not `undefined`.

I hope this helps someone else!